# How to guess a math function programmatically?

Tags: algorithm, math, brute-force

I have some inputs and outputs of a math function in a two-dimensional array, like this:

```
. . . . .
[[  3,  2, -2,  3, -2 ],  5]
[[  0,  0,  1, -1, -1 ],  1]
[[  2,  2,  1,  2, -3 ],  1]
[[ -1,  0,  2,  2,  1 ],  3]
. . . . .
```

I want to understand what this function is. It certainly does some arithmetic to the inputs, so I can do something like (pseudocode here:)

```
while(true){
    newExpr = constructNextExpression(
        add, sub, mul, div, 
        Lparan, Rparan, sqr, sqrt, 
        a, b, c, d, e, result
    )
    found = true
    for (values in valueArray){
        if(eval(newExpr(values) == false)) {
            found = false
            break
        }        
    }
    if(found) return newExpr
}
```

But this seems like brute force to me, so I am not sure I should take this approach. What are some other, perhaps wiser, approaches?

Comment: You might want to try your luck on the math stack exchange site...

Comment: Is this a [reverse-engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question, perhaps?

Comment: I don't know if it is more math or reverse engineering, so first of all I put it here. I am not sure, maybe you are right and it doesn't belong here.

Comment: Unless you can limit your search to a narrow subclass of expressions - it will not be possible to find an analytical solution.

Comment: You can try and look into neural networks if you are after abstracting a function which returns the same values, however, this does not give you the actual function itself.
Note, however, than from a mathematical perspective, infinitely many functions can give you the same answer, so you would need to have some hard constraints.

Comment: Looks like you're seeking some variant of [multiple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression).  You'd do best to use a statistical software package rather than trying to implement it on your own.  I'd recommend https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I agree completely that mathematically speaking there are infinitely many functions; actually I need just one that would give the same results. I am trying to simplify a long redundant expression which produces short integers but it looks like I am getting rather stuck than anything else with this approach.

Comment: This is not a Countdown puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solvable, given enough flexibility *and* specificity in the paradigm.

For starters, you can fit *any* set of `N` points with a polynomial of total degree no more than `N`; you can fiddle with your equation parameters to achieve the desired degree of each of the variables.  The most familiar example is `N` equations in `N` variables, generally solvable (with no equivalent or inconsistent linear equations) with simple linear matrix operations, yielding each of the `N` variables with degree 1.

I suggest that you look for simple equation solvers in your preferred language; most of them allow you to specify desired degree of equation.

Comment: Thank you for your attention even with this question being downvoted! Do I get it right that it is a variant of the same expression generation and evaluation approach?

Comment: No; my suggestion is not genetic or organic.  Count the variables in your inputs.  Select an equation class with exactly the needed quantity of degrees of freedom.  Feed those to a solver and receive a suitable set of function coefficients.

Comment: Now I get it, with n arguments I will take a polynomial of degree n and use an existing solver. This looks much more efficient than generation of permutated expressions and straightforward evaluation of those. Thank you.

Comment: Right!  Adjust degree as needed: for instance, if you have 7 equations in 5 variables, you may well have to add quadratic terms for two of the variables.